# Multiple Sites on IIS with PHP - SSL Issue

Tags: php, iis, ssl

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server with IIS 7.5 installed and PHP 5.6.6.

I have a site set up that is using a SSL certificate which is working fine (domain1.com).

I am now trying to setup a second PHP site (domain2.com) which does not require SSL.

When I browse to domain2.com I get the following error in Chrome:

**This server could not prove that it is domain2.com; its security certificate is from domain1.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.**

Somewhere there is a setting that is forcing domain2.com to try and use SSL but I cannot see where and cannot find any solutions by searching the Internet.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

Used a wildcard certificate to resolve this in the end.